# How to determine the last 1k blocks and their Miner Software?

Tags: blockchain, block, network, charts

Basically the idea was to create a tiny service such as [nodecounter.com](http://nodecounter.com/).

Now I would appreciate your help on the following questions:

- How to determine the Software (Core, Classic, XT, etc.) and quantity on the whole network?
- How to determine the last 1k blocks and their Miner Software?

I would start from scratch, but if you know about any open source projects, preferably in NodeJS or PHP, I would really appreciate a hint.

Answer (score 2):

> How to determine the Software (Core, Classic, XT, etc.) and quantity
>   on the whole network?

connect to host and take the 'user-agent' string from 'version' packet

> How to determine the last 1k blocks and their Miner Software?

the miner can be determined by analyzing coinbase transaction.

the software can not be determined